# Accessing different google calendar through zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, google-calendar-api

I am new to the Google Calendar API and have worked through what I think is a good tutorial to allow me to view and add events to my calendar using the zend framework.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googleclndr/

I have got my pages working as per the example, but I can only connect to my default calendar and I wish to connect to a different one.

I found an example on the zend site to loop through all instances of my calendar, so I see what looks like my username in the uri, but replacing the username in my code doesn't work.

Can anyone advise how to view/edit a different google calendar ?

thanks

**Update, by changing the $query->setUser parameter, in the event listing code, i managed to connect to a different calendar.

How would I do something similar for event insert ?

Comment: Update, I  managed to find out an answer through another post.

in the try {} construct, add another parameter to $gcal->insertEvent($event), make it $gcal->insertEvent($event, $uri);

in the preceding line, set $uri to the calendar address, ensuring the last parameter is /full  . Same logic applies to editing an event